# NSUserDefaults return nil for previously set values on debug builds

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I have a strange issue with `NSUserDefaults`. I set a value like this:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults.setObject("Test", forKey: "test")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults.synchronize()
```

And I retrieve it like that

```
let storedValue = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults.objectForKey("test")
```

The problem now is, that sometimes, not always, when recompiling the app onto my device, `storedValue == nil`. Even if no part of my app ever removed that value!!!

How can it be that that value gets nil? Is there a way that UserDefaults get deleted somehow? I only noticed the problem when doing a recompile onto the device. Without a debugger attached it always behaves like it should (I use it to show an intro screen, so I can see if it works).

Comment: Is that a typo in your question? Your two keys are different.

Comment: That was just a typo in the question, yes. In the app thats correct

Comment: Did you find any solution? I got the exact same problem on my application. Sometimes the value is nil, sometimes not.

Comment: Nope... I resetted my phone (and did not restore from anything... pretty annoying!!!!) and it was good for a long time. But I still see the problem every now and then... but at least not that often any more... Fun thing is that if affects every single app on my phone that stores things in the UserDefaults... like WhatsApp, Facebook, Youtube... really really annoying!!!